# delete date in the name of all the sheets in the book

Tags: vba, excel

I copy several sheets in a new file by VBA. All these sheets have a current date in the end of the name like "YYYYMMDD". How can I remove the date part? I tried this, but it did not work:

sheets are `A.20131226`, `B.20131226`, and `C.20131226` for example

```
Dim SheetNames As Variant
SheetNames = Array( "A", B", "C")
If ActiveSheet.Name = SheetNames + "." + VBA.Format(asofdate, "yyyyMMdd") Then
ActiveSheet.Name = SheetNames
End If
```

Comment: If you want new name "A" for a sheet named "A.foobar", just check the first character of the name and set it as the new name. No need to make strings with ending date.

Answer (score 3):

you said all these sheets have a current date in the end of the name...
but why are you making an "if" statement? You could just cut the last part off:

```
 newname = Left(oldname, Len(oldname) - 9)
```

(9 because of the ".yyyyMMdd" String)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Sub SheetNameFixer()
Dim s As Worksheet
For Each s In Sheets
    st = s.Name
    NumPart = Right(st, 8)
    If IsNumeric(NumPart) Then
        s.Name = Left(st, Len(st) - 8)
    End If
Next s
End Sub
```